# Logo image overflow into content

Tags: html, css, web

Hello I'm currently working on a website where I want the logo of the business to overlap into the content.

Similar to this website: http://www.menzies.com.au/

I'm not really sure how to approach this problem, I tried using negative margin, and z-index, but it just felt like the wrong approach

Example Code of what i've tried

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <img src="logo.jpg" style="float: left; z-index: 3;">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="http://all4desktop.com/data_images/original/4172874-nordic-landscapes.jpg" style="z-index: -1; margin-top: -50px;">
</div>
```

What's occurring is that the second image is overlapping the logo image. It also just feels like a clunky way to approach the problem as I've never seen people advocate using negative margin unless absolutely necessary

Could anyone with experience in doing this point me in the right direction?

Comment: use css `position:fixed` or `position:absolute` on the logo. read more about it on google.

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you need do is set the logo position to `absolute`, then it will be over the other elements. I did a example to you, look at this HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

The `menu` div has 75px of height, but his child can have more than this, and if they do, a overflow will occur, that is what you wanna. If it doesn't occur, as I said, you can try set the position to `absolute`. So, you set the `logo` div to something like 130px of height, and the `nav` to 100% height. I changed the height of `logo` to 130px, but it doesn't affect the other menu child. So, the `nav` height will be the `menu` height: 75px. Complete code:

```css
#menu {
    width:100%;
    height:75px;
    background-color:#333;
}

ul {
    list-style:none;
}

ul li {
    display:inline-block;
}

.logo {
    width:150px;
    height:130px;
    background-image:url('http://placehold.it/150x130');
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:25px;
}

nav {
    color:#fff;
    float:right;
    font-size:1.3em;
    line-height:75px;
    margin-right:10px;
    height:100%;
}

nav ul {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

nav ul li {
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

This problem is very relative, but with a simple CSS like this one, you can contour this.